# Jest/Enzyme is there a matcher for a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component method that returns and other component. Is there a Jest matcher to test this?

For example, my component has the following method:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  selectDashboardView(dashboard) {
    if (!dashboard) {
      return null;
    }

    switch (dashboard) {
      case DASHBOARD_TYPE.advisor:
        return <AdvisorDashboard />;

      case DASHBOARD_TYPE.advisor_fund:
        return <AdvisorFundDashboard />;

      case DASHBOARD_TYPE.portfolio:
        return <PortfolioDashboard />;

      case DASHBOARD_TYPE.investor_profile:
        return <InvestorProfileDashboard />;

      case DASHBOARD_TYPE.investment:
        return <InvestmentDashboard />;

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I would like to be able to write a test like this (obviously, this is not a valid test):

```
describe('App', () => {
  test('selects proper dashboard', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    expect(instance.selectDashboardView('advisor')).toMatch(<AdvisorDashboard />);

  });
});
```

**Update:**
It may be important to note that these components are connected to Redux. When testing `<App />`, I imported the unconnected component, the same with `<AdvisorDashboard />`, etc... I was able to solve the problem with the following code:

```
describe('App', () => {
  test('selects proper dashboard', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App setDashboard={mockFn} setIsAdvisor={mockFn} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    expect(instance.selectDashboardView('advisor').type.WrappedComponent).toEqual(AdvisorDashboard);
    expect(instance.selectDashboardView('investor_profile').type.WrappedComponent).toEqual(InvestorProfileDashboard);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try matching the component name

```
expect(instance.selectDashboardView('advisor').constructor.name)
 .toMatch(AdvisorDashboard.name);
```

or according to the [doc](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/type.html) you can use the `type` method

```
expect(instance.selectDashboardView('advisor').type()).to.equal(AdvisorDashboard);
```

Comment: Neither of these worked for me. If I log out `instance.selectDashboardView('advisor').constructor.name` I get `Object`. Using `type()` errors as the docs say it "can only be called on a wrapper..."